# Minishift: Problems starting

Tags: redhat-containers

I am trying to get minishift runnin on my machine (Windows 10) with Virtualbox 5.1.24. 
Minishift version: 1.0.0+4f8cb6d

CDK Version: 3.0.0-2

Starting minishift gives me the following:

```
C:\>minishift start --vm-driver virtualbox
Starting local OpenShift cluster using 'virtualbox' hypervisor...
E0727 18:34:21.682796   17204 start.go:176] Error starting the VM: Error 
creating new host: Error attempting to get plugin server address for RPC: 
Failed to dial the plugin server in 10s. Retrying.
E0727 18:34:31.740746   17204 start.go:176] Error starting the VM: Error 
creating new host: Error attempting to get plugin server address for RPC: 
Failed to dial the plugin server in 10s. Retrying.
E0727 18:34:41.770667   17204 start.go:176] Error starting the VM: Error 
creating new host: Error attempting to get plugin server address for RPC: 
Failed to dial the plugin server in 10s. Retrying.
Error starting the VM:  Error creating new host: Error attempting to get 
plugin server address for RPC: Failed to dial the plugin server in 10s
Error creating new host: Error attempting to get plugin server address for 
RPC: Failed to dial the plugin server in 10s
Error creating new host: Error attempting to get plugin server address for       
RPC: Failed to dial the plugin server in 10s
```

I read the comments that it needs to run from the C:\drive but it looks like this did not fix the problem. I am happy about any hints how to fix this. If there is any additional information you need, just let me know.

Comment: It works with a minishift 1.3.0 - is the packaged solution supposed to work?

Comment: I am using minishift 1.3.0 and still getting below error frequenty- Error attempting to get plugin server address for RPC: Failed to dial the plugin server in 10s

Comment: Hi Kuldeep, which driver? which OS? which VM solution? please give us some more information to work with.

Comment: Hey Alex, Actually it works after giving 2-3 retires ;).

Comment: Have you got it to consistently work? It came up once but can't get it to work again after multiple retries.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you got it working.

I usually encourage folks who are having trouble starting their minishift VMs to try the following:

1. [Find your preferred virtualization provider from the list of available options](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/getting-started/installing.html#install-prerequisites)
2. [Install the appropriate driver plugin for your system](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/getting-started/setting-up-driver-plugin.html)
3. Persist your VM provider configuration: `minishift config set vm-driver virualbox`

Comment: I am having the same problem, with just starting minishift up for the same time.   The link under (2) returns "docs.okd.io redirected you too many times."    My issue, from "https://docs.okd.io/3.11/minishift/getting-started/setting-up-virtualization-environment.html#setting-up-hyper-v-driver", is that creating an External Switch fails - "has not been granted those access rights"